# Connecting 4G device to router

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge-router

I have [this](https://www.jio.com/preview/jiofi) 4G device without a LAN port which I want to use to share internet with a few desktops. Desktops and a printer are networked. I guess with Wireless Distribution System(WDS) mechanism in the router (like TP-Link [TL-WR840N](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR840N.html)), the router can be bridged to the 4G device without any wire. The point I am not sure about is whether I will be able to access the shared printer on the networked desktops through the router. Can it be done so?

PS: Also, since both the 4G device as well as router will be placed very close to each other, will this not create interference?

Answer (score 0):

WDS is real bridging, so all the devices in your network will act just like they were connected with wires. However, performance may be poor because both devices will have to use the same channel and a lot of traffic will get transmitted twice.

There's no particular reason to think there will be interference between the two devices. If you're really worried about it, place them a few feet apart.

Comment: Thanks for your response. By interference, I really meant what you just said - poor performance because of transmission issues. Can we somehow get rid of or atleast minimise this issue? Can I keep the ssids different on both the devices?

Comment: I don't think you'll have any such issues.